# Is it possible to extract the substream key in akkastreams?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I can't seem to find any documentation on this but I know that AkkaStreams stores the keys used to group a stream into substreams when calling **groupBy** in memory. Is it possible to extract those keys from the substream? Say I create a bunch of substreams from my main stream, pass those through a fold that counts the objects in each substream and then store the count in a class. Can I get the key of the substream to also pass to that class? Or is there a better way of doing this? I need to count each element per substream but I also need to store which group the count belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice example is shown in the [stream-cookbook](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-cookbook.html):

```
val counts: Source[(String, Int), NotUsed] = words
// split the words into separate streams first
  .groupBy(MaximumDistinctWords, identity)
  //transform each element to pair with number of words in it
  .map(_ -> 1)
  // add counting logic to the streams
  .reduce((l, r) => (l._1, l._2 + r._2))
  // get a stream of word counts
  .mergeSubstreams
```

Then the following:

```
val words = Source(List("Hello", "world", "let's", "say", "again", "Hello", "world"))
counts.runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
```

Will print:

```
(world,2)
(Hello,2)
(let's,1)
(again,1)
(say,1)
```

Another example I thought of, was counting numbers by their remainders. So the following, as example:

```
Source(0 to 101)
  .groupBy(10, x => x % 4)
  .map(e => e % 4 -> 1)
  .reduce((l, r) => (l._1, l._2 + r._2))
  .mergeSubstreams.to(Sink.foreach(println)).run()
```

will print:

```
(0,26)
(1,26)
(2,25)
(3,25)
```

Comment: This strategy works for what I need! However, I need two pipelines that do this asynchronously. When I  implement this, for some reason, after merging the pipelines together I only get like 3 items when there should be thousands. If I do it with a fold, all entries get outputted but half of them miss the key value. Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: @WolfDeWulf, It's really hard to know without seeing your code. However, each SO question should have only one question. If my answer answers your question, you can accept it, and create another question regarding your non working code.